# Is there a proof for the FOIL method in Boolean algebra?

Tags: boolean-algebra

The FOIL method is the special case of multiplying algebraic expressions using the distributive law and is shown here:

[image]

What does the proof for this look like using Boolean algebra?

Comment: Boolean algebra has distributivity, no? That's all you need.

Answer (score 1):

As Boolean expression, this works out similarly:

Conjunctive Normal Form ([CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form), product-of-sums):

> (a+b) & (c+d)

Equivalent Disjunctive Normal Form ([DNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form), sum of products):

> ac + ad + bc + bd

Karnaugh map:

```
             ab
       00  01  11  10
      +---+---+---+---+
   00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
      +---+---+---+---+
   01 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
cd    +---+---+---+---+
   11 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
      +---+---+---+---+
   10 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
      +---+---+---+---+
```